# ValueError: axes don't match array encountered while using MTCNN

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision

I am trying to find faces in a greyscale Image of size (48 x 48). The code is pretty straightforward here, however I am unable to find what's wrong with the input.
`np.expand_dims` was used because the detector needs shape in the form of (x, y, z). Since the images I am using are greyscale, they are in 48 x 48 and there is no third axis as compared to what RGB images have.

```py
    from PIL import Image
    import numpy as np
    import os
    path = './Dataset/anger/'
    detector = mtcnn.MTCNN()
    pixels = np.asarray(np.expand_dims(Image.open(os.path.join(path, os.listdir(path)[0])), -1))
    print(pixels.shape)
    # detect faces in the image
    faces = detector.detect_faces(pixels)
    for face in faces:
        print(face)
```

This is the output and tracebacks:

```
(48, 48, 1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-ec1134efa98f> in <module>()
      7 print(pixels.shape)
      8 # detect faces in the image
----> 9 faces = detector.detect_faces(pixels)
     10 for face in faces:
     11     print(face)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mtcnn/mtcnn.py in detect_faces(self, img)
    298         # We pipe here each of the stages
    299         for stage in stages:
--> 300             result = stage(img, result[0], result[1])
    301 
    302         [total_boxes, points] = result

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mtcnn/mtcnn.py in __stage1(self, image, scales, stage_status)
    338 
    339             img_x = np.expand_dims(scaled_image, 0)
--> 340             img_y = np.transpose(img_x, (0, 2, 1, 3))
    341 
    342             out = self._pnet.predict(img_y)

<__array_function__ internals> in transpose(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in transpose(a, axes)
    651 
    652     """
--> 653     return _wrapfunc(a, 'transpose', axes)
    654 
    655 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     56 
     57     try:
---> 58         return bound(*args, **kwds)
     59     except TypeError:
     60         # A TypeError occurs if the object does have such a method in its

ValueError: axes don't match array
```

Python version: 3.8
Mtcnn version: 0.1.0

Comment: In line 340, the `transpose` assumes the `img_x` has 4 dimensions.  According to your print `pixels` is 3d.  What does `detect_faces` require?  I haven't used that package.

Comment: When I went for the image without using np.expand_dims, this is the error I get. It feels like they want me to use something with 3 axes like so.
```(48, 48)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)```

Comment: `detect_faces` starts with a `height, width, _ = img.shape` line.  `img` is a supposed to be 3d, typical for a color image.  In the error line, `img_y = np.transpose(img_x, (0, 2, 1, 3))` it has added a leading dimension to `img_x`, so it is now 4d, and the transpose it just switching `height` and `width` dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...
The problem was that MTCNN doesn't work with Greyscale Images and had to do something to mimic the RGB images, so I repeated the matrix thrice to make it
so that the shape looked something like `(length, width, 3)` by using `np.repeat({48 x 48 matrix}, 3, axis=-1)`

So if you are facing a similar problem as me where the data resembles that of FER2013 challenge dataset and looks like

```
       0                                                  1
0      0  126 69 48 71 84 90 93 87 97 107 116 115 106 10...
1      0  62 83 105 82 30 17 33 35 33 38 25 14 44 95 110...
2      0  204 199 186 171 112 52 45 43 37 50 68 80 86 89...
3      0  105 130 127 93 110 142 133 131 140 142 145 147...
4      0  187 187 187 187 187 187 187 187 184 184 187 18...
...   ..                                                ...
31282  6  106 101 85 98 89 84 88 119 82 105 87 60 76 98 ...
31283  6  29 26 19 18 28 21 16 23 29 18 22 18 17 13 12 1...
31284  6  24 22 25 21 20 23 29 31 34 42 52 57 64 64 69 6...
31285  6  5 4 5 9 10 9 10 12 8 14 13 17 24 26 36 48 67 7...
31286  6  103 132 154 165 176 182 190 195 201 203 208 21...
```

Where col 0 is the class and col 1 is the image data which is basically a string where the pixel data is separated using a space, here's a funky one-liner you can try to preprocess the data the way MTCNN likes it.

```
test_df.iloc[:, 1] = np.asarray(map(lambda x: np.repeat(np.expand_dims(np.reshape([np.float32(l) for l in x.split()], (48, 48)), axis=-1), 3, axis=-1), test_df.iloc[:, 1]))
```

Note that test_df is a simple `pd.read_csv()` result of the data that i talked about above.